# how to use Jenkins for .NET Builds in a centOS environment

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild, centos

First of all, I do not understand in .net.. but, I need to build exist project in jenkins..

So, I want to build .NET project in jenkins, my machine is centOS.

I didnt find any guide to do this..

Also, I dont want to use Slave machine or virtual machine.

It's possible? What do I need? I understend that [MSBuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin) is needed.. but what more? and how do i install MSbuild on centOS?

Comment: Your question is like "I want to climb up a mountain without climbing", so I don't think any answer can be given. If the "existing project" requires MSBuild and Windows, then you can only build a slave machine using Windows OS. There is no alternative.

Comment: Hi @LexLi and thank you for the answer! I'm really looking for another solution. maybe install mono on centos solved this? it's enough?

Comment: Its all dependent on the how you resolve the dependencies. Either in Nix or Win. AFAIK building .Net projects in Windows is the best unique way to avoid alien errors.

Comment: @ShiraOzeri Mono != .NET don't dream it would solve your problem.

Comment: Ok @LexLi, you convinced me. I solve it with slave machine. thank everybody!

Comment: Building on mono is sort of okay (if it works for your project!!) since the compiler is the same and the reference assemblies are compatible, but I wouldn't completely trust unit tests. But it works well for quite a few open source projects.